# sinatra redirect on error

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I'm having problem with redirecting on error in Sinatra modular app.
I'm deploying on Heroku and when there is an error, application dies.

I'd like it to catch this error, redirect to error page and operate normally.

I've set in my base class things as below:

```
set :raise_errors, false
```

and

```
error do
    redirect to('/')
end
```

but when I `raise` error from within route block it just goes to standard Sinatra error page.

What I need to do to catch my errors and redirect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You also need

```
set :show_exceptions, false
```

Here's a simple demo

```
require "sinatra"

class App < Sinatra::Base

    set :raise_errors, false
    set :show_exceptions, false

    get '/' do
        return 'Hello, World!'
    end

    get '/error' do
        return 'You tried to divide by zero!'
    end

    get '/not-found' do
        return 'There is nothing there'
    end

    get '/raise500' do
        raise 500
    end

    get '/divide-by-zero' do
        x = 5/0
    end

    error do
        redirect to('/')
    end

    error 404 do
        redirect to('/not-found')
    end

    error ZeroDivisionError do
        redirect to('/error')
    end

end
```

Without `:show_exceptions` set `/raise500` and `/divide-by-zero` return the generic Sinatra error page, but with it they redirect as you would expect.